# How to make code react to raw_input / input correctly ( python )

Tags: python

Hello im working on a simple chat and it got an feedback option in it, how do i correctly make this code work? ps this is my first py code. Thanks in advance!
extra: i would like

else:
"go back to FeedbackQ"

how to properly define that in code? (py ofc)
here's my code so far:

```
FeedbackQ = raw_input("good / medium / bad :")           

if FeedbackQ == good:
print ("Thank you for using our service we are satisfied now.")

if FeedbackQ == medium:
print ("Thank you're feedback, we are working on the code.")

if FeedbackQ == bad:
print ("Thank you for you're feedback, please contact us for bugs.")

else:
raise SystemExit # edit to repeat question!
```

"pavlov kobrinsky"

Comment: You may want to read about [loops](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_flow#Loops).

Note also that the `else` in your current code refers to the preceding `if`, so that branch of the code only runs when `FeedbackQ` is not `bad`. You may want to read about [basic control flow in Python](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html).

Comment: You should use "medium" as a string and not as a variable/objects. You are comparing 2 objects and out of which one is not defined. Either compare with the string value or store the string value inside the object.

Comment: you need to change that comparisons to strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this with the following code.

```
while True:
    FeedbackQ = raw_input("good / medium / bad :")           
    
    if FeedbackQ == "good":
        print ("Thank you for using our service we are satisfied now.")
        break
    
    if FeedbackQ == "medium":
        print ("Thank you're feedback, we are working on the code.")
        break
    
    if FeedbackQ == "bad":
        print ("Thank you for you're feedback, please contact us for bugs.")
        break
```

And I will recommend you go through [this link to have more understanding of control flow](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html).

Comment: Got it working thanks for the help, i found out using "sleep (%)"  it restarts. thanks \